# How to Trigger a GTM event based on Cookie is accepted or not

Tags: google-tag-manager

There is a piece of script in GTM ( as tag ) that needs to trigger only when user accepts a particular cookie. Problem is - I have added a script belonging to the particular cookie category via GTM. When a user wants to accept only analytics ( GTM loads as expected ), the script I have added via GTM which belongs to another cookie category ( not analytics ) also fires ( Ideally it shouldn't cos only analytics is accepted by the user )
. Is there a way to trigger GTM event only when cookie is accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you're looking to load the functional script ONLY if they accept AND functional cookie is 'yes'

In GTM, there are "Variables" that can keep track of 1st party cookies. So in y our case you would want to:

**Create a variable to track the functional cookie value**
[image]

**create the trigger based on clicking on "accept" and it would just be conditional based on the value being "yes" (you will need to create your custom functional script tag beforehand)**
[image]

**Add the trigger to the functional tag**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, It worked with a slight change. In the 2nd step instead of selecting "Click - All Elements", selecting a 'Custom event' with regex matching checked and in input field - .* . So that the trigger will work in all kinds of events. Else it was somhow not firing. :)